# AngularJS: function seems to be firing multiple time

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, angularjs, angular-routing

I am building an employee directory and I recently changed the way my contentCtrl function works in an attempt to make the Angular routes more flexible.

Old code

```js
//the contentCtrl function is what drives the main body of the app, it uses the active id to pull the relevant JSON file from the file structure
    //it then breaks that json file apart based on who is labled "primary", "seconday", and "tertiary" these teammates are placed into 
    //arrays labled based on thier position data field, we then use angular to populate the page
    //so the manager of a program is in primary, so we use item in primary and item.fname etc to pull the program manager into the page
    //we then use item in secondary to pull in the next person (assistant manager) and finally we use item in tertiary to
    //pull in all of the teammates remaining in a department
    $scope.contentCtrl = function(id) {
        $scope.active = [];
        $scope.activeTwo = [];
        $scope.primary = [];
        $scope.secondary = [];
        $scope.tertiary = [];
        $scope.credits = [];
        $http.get('assets/json/' + id + '.json').then(function(response) {
            $scope.active = response.data;
            //loops through the json file and pulls out primary,secondary, and tertiary employees
            for (var i = 0; i < $scope.active.length; i++) {
                if ($scope.active[i].layout == "primary") {
                    $scope.primary.push($scope.active[i]);
                } else if ($scope.active[i].layout == "secondary") {
                    $scope.secondary.push($scope.active[i]);
                } else {
                    $scope.tertiary.push($scope.active[i]);
                }
            }

        });
        $http.get('assets/json/credits.json').then(function(response) {
            $scope.activeTwo = response.data;
            for (var i = 0; i < $scope.activeTwo.length; i++) {
                $scope.credits.push($scope.activeTwo[i]);
            }

        });

    };
```

New code

```js
$scope.contentCtrl = function(id) {
        console.log(id);
        $rootScope.activeID = id;
        $rootScope.active = [];
        $rootScope.activeTwo = [];
        $rootScope.primary = [];
        $rootScope.secondary = [];
        $rootScope.tertiary = [];
        $rootScope.credits = [];
        $http.get('assets/json/' + $rootScope.activeID + '.json').then(function(response) {
            $scope.active = response.data;
            //loops through the json file and pulls out primary,secondary, and tertiary employees
            for (var i = 0; i < $scope.active.length; i++) {
                if ($scope.active[i].layout == "primary") {
                    $scope.primary.push($scope.active[i]);
                } else if ($scope.active[i].layout == "secondary") {
                    $scope.secondary.push($scope.active[i]);
                } else {
                    $scope.tertiary.push($scope.active[i]);
                }
            }


        });
        $http.get('assets/json/credits.json').then(function(response) {
            $scope.activeTwo = response.data;
            for (var i = 0; i < $scope.activeTwo.length; i++) {
                $scope.credits.push($scope.activeTwo[i]);
            }

        });


    };
```

and here is the HTML that is using this function to display the employees

```html
<!-- sets the primary teammate via a function located in the controller.js file please view that file for a description of HOW the function works, once the function is done however this ul places the teammate labeled primary into a position in the top left of the screen (determined by css, can be moved), the image, name, and position are all done through ng repeat and the image is an ng-click to pass the teammate in the image to the modal that pops up. So 
    1) page loads
    2) controller splits json file into three arrays primary, secondary, and tertiary
    3) we use angular to to pull from these arrays (item in primary) 
    4) item in primary for instance is Andy Johnson, so item.fname is Andy, item.lName is Johnson. These data fields are defined in the JSON file for each department
    5) the image, when clicked, calls the function modalPass() and gives the parameter item, which in this instance is Andy Johnsons json data
    6) the modalPass() function then saves whatever was passed in (item aka Andy Johnson) as an object called teammateInfo, hence on line 55 we use teammate Info.fName instead of item.fName -->
        <ul class="primary">
            <li ng-repeat="item in primary">
                <a ng-click="modalPass(item)" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#teammateModal" /> <img class="directoryImg" ng-src={{item.image}}></a>
                <h4>{{item.fName}} {{item.lName}}</h4>
                <h4>{{item.pos}}</h4>
            </li>
        </ul>
        <ul class="secondary">
            <li style="width: 220px; margin-right:80px;" ng-repeat="item in secondary">
                <a ng-click="modalPass(item)" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#teammateModal" /> <img class="directoryImg" ng-src={{item.image}}></a>
                <h4>{{item.fName}} {{item.lName}}</h4>
                <h4>{{item.pos}}</h4>
            </li>
        </ul>
        <ul class="tertiary">
            <li ng-class="sizeCheck(tertiary.length)" class="col-lg-1" ng-repeat="item in tertiary">
                <div style="position: relative; left: 0; top: 0;">
                    <a ng-click="modalPass(item)" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#teammateModal" /> <img class="directoryImg" ng-src={{item.image}}>
                    <img ng-if="item.BOB != 'false'" class="BOB" src="./assets/images/icons/svg/BOB.svg">
                    <img ng-if="item.TCE != 'false'" class="TCE" src="./assets/images/icons/svg/TCE.svg"></a>
                    <img ng-if="item.GSC != 'false'" class="GSC" src="./assets/images/icons/svg/GSC.png"></a>
                </div>
                <h4 style="line-height:1;">{{item.fName}} {{item.lName}}<br>{{item.pos}}</h4>
            </li>
        </ul>
```

This made it work but I am almost certain this is a poor solution, I am new to Angular and Javascript but I do know that you shouldn't use global variables unless it is absolutely needed, so I am open to help with that part of the function. But that isn't my current problem. The problem I am having is that when I put in a console log it seems to be calling the function 3-4 times. I don't have an errors but it makes me uncomfortable because I can't understand why it is behaving this way. Can anyone explain if this is normal or help me find a solution if it is a bug in my code.

Comment: are you hooking you controller multiple times on the view, also can you make a fiddle or plunkr of your code.

Comment: @SadiRubaiyet I will try to make a fiddle when I get back to my work computer tomorrow. I'm not sure what you mean by hooking my controller multiple times, I only call the controller one time like so `<div id="wrapper" ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="teammateController">`

Comment: hmm, also check your routes and make sure there is no duplicate.

Comment: @SadiRubaiyet will do, thanks for the advice

Comment: also another thing you can do is set a breakpoint or debugger statement before console.log and see the stack trace to find where the call is coming form.